# onclick event is triggered without clicking

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick

This is a simple dice throwing event, 6 dice, generated by a random number, everything works, I'm getting the data in the console but I want it triggered only when clicking on the button.

in this code the onclick event is triggered (in the console) without me clicking, how can I fix that?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="eng">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Yahtzee Project OOP</title>
  <link href= rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Dice Project</h1>

  <button id="rollButton">ROLL CLICK HERE</button>

<script>
    
  var results = [
    {rollCounter: 0},
    {dieNumber: 1, rollResult: 'NULL', check: 'NULL'},
    {dieNumber: 2, rollResult: 'NULL', check: 'NULL'},
    {dieNumber: 3, rollResult: 'NULL', check: 'NULL'},
    {dieNumber: 4, rollResult: 'NULL', check: 'NULL'},
    {dieNumber: 5, rollResult: 'NULL', check: 'NULL'}
  ];

  var clickButton = document.getElementById('rollButton');


  function print(message){
    document.write(message);
  }

  function randomRoll(){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
  }

  function rollDice(results){
    for (var i=1; i<6; i++){
        results[i].rollResult = randomRoll();
    }
    console.log(results);
    return results;
  }

  clickButton.onclick = rollDice(results);

</script>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 13):

That's because you're assigning the *result* of executing `rollDice(results)` to your `clickButton.onclick` function. You're not telling it to execute that function when the element is clicked. To avoid this, wrap that in a function call itself:

```
clickButton.onclick = function() { rollDice(results); }
```

Now your click will execute that function which only then executes the `rollDice` function.

---

To expand on what's happening here. Let's say we have a function `foo` which returns the string `"bar"`:

```
function foo() { return "bar"; }
```

If we're to assign `foo()` to a new variable, JavaScript will execute the `foo` function there and then and assign the result of that function to our new variable:

```
var baz = foo();
-> "bar"
```

However if we place our `foo()` function call within another function call, our original function will not be immediately executed:

```
var baz = function() { return foo(); }
-> function() { return foo(); }
```

If we now call `baz()`, it will execute its own function which itself executes our original `foo` function:

```
baz();
-> "bar"
```

The same applies with your `onclick` function. Rather than telling the `onclick` to execute our function when the element is clicked, we're assigning `"bar"` to our `onclick` function:

```
elem.onclick = foo();
-> "bar"
```

Comment: Thank you James, it works, but I don't fully understand why. I'll have to play around a bit

Comment: @jayNorth I've updated my answer. Let me know if that makes it any clearer. :)

Comment: sorry but I'm even more confused now, the foo bar examples never really make sense to me. Let me sleep on it and it might sink in.

Comment: If you try this solution and it does not work either. Maybe it's because you are calling the function at the bottom of your code. This was my case …https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54840493/event-triggers-immediately-after-reload-not-after-onclick).