# Event triggers immediately after reload. Not after "onclick"

Tags: javascript, triggers, onclick

On the way to my first Pomodoro-App (timer) shipwrecking with `oncLick`, which should start the counter…
**It starts even without beeing triggered by button click. How can I prevent that?**

```js
let display = document.getElementById("counter");

document.getElementById("ticker").onclick = function() {
  timeChange(25);
};

// document.getElementById("ticker").addEventListener("click", function() {
//   timeChange(25);
// });

function timeChange(seconds) {
  // let seconds = 25;
  seconds -= 1;
  display.innerText = seconds;
  page.firstChild.nodeValue = seconds;
  if (seconds > 0) {
    setTimeout(timeChange, 1000, seconds);
  }
}
timeChange(25);
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="page">
    <div id="counter"></div>
    <button id="ticker">Start Pomodoro</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

I already found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742543/onclick-event-is-triggered-without-clicking) to the same(?) issue:

> That's because you're assigning the result of executing
>   rollDice(results) to your clickButton.onclick function

But I did not(?) assign the result of my function to `onclick`

Is it because of the argument (25) I put into the function to which the `onclick` is assigned to?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: It's because you're calling `timeChange(25)` at the bottom of the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove:
`timeChange(25);`
from the bottom of your code