# onclick event is triggered before an element is clicked

Tags: javascript

This is the code that I have with `onclick` event listener.

```js
function makeSizer(size) {
    alert(size)
    document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
}

document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = makeSizer(14);
document.getElementById('size-14').onclick = makeSizer(16);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
    <p>Some paragraph text</p>

    <a href="#" id="size-12">12</a>
    <a href="#" id="size-14">14</a>
```

However, I have no idea why once browser is loaded, the clicked event is triggered immediately or before I actually click the link. Could you help me explain this.

One solution that I got is to use closure like below by returning a function. I wonder if you have any others?

```
function makeSizer(size) {
    return function (){
        alert(size)
    document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
    }       
}
```

By the way, there may be a dulplicate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32742543/onclick-event-is-triggered-without-clicking). However, I'm seeking more general explanation/discussion than debugging.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function makeSizer(size) {
    alert(size)
    document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
}

document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = function() { 
  makeSizer(14);
}

document.getElementById('size-14').onclick = {
  makeSizer(16);
}
```

Comment: You were setting the onclick property to a function that you were immediately calling.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the result returned by `makeSizer(14)` to the element's `onclick` attribute.

If you want `makeSizer(14)` to be called on click, wrap it in a function:

```js
function makeSizer(size) {
  alert(size)
  document.body.style.fontSize = size + 'px';
}

document.getElementById('size-12').onclick = () => makeSizer(14);
document.getElementById('size-14').onclick = () => makeSizer(16);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<p>Some paragraph text</p>

<a href="#" id="size-12">12</a>
<a href="#" id="size-14">14</a>
```

Comment: this may sound a bit silly, but do you know why makeSizers is triggered immediately without being wrapped in a function?